# Can HTTPHandler track download cancelled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, httphandler

I'm trying to track the number of times a file is being downloaded, and who has downloaded it. Since there is no way to get any click event from the File SaveAs dialog box, I want to know if the handler can actually know if a download is cancelled or the user chooses to download it?

This link [ASP.NET file download - detect if user cancelled download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614001/asp-net-file-download-detect-if-user-cancelled-download) suggested having another confirmation dialog box to get the job done, but I figure that this might not be a user-friendly kind of approach.

I'm not ruling out the possibility of mis-clicking the download button, so I just want to know if there is really some way to know when to increase the downloaded times.

UPDATE:

I have this code now after doing some reading up.

```
    int maxCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((file.Length - startBytes + 0.0) / 1024);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < maxCount && context.Response.IsClientConnected; i++)
    {
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(_BinaryReader.ReadBytes(1024));
        context.Response.Flush();
    }

    if (i < maxCount)
    { }
    else
    {
        //Update Increment
    }
```

I'm still trying to make the cancel event notified, so that I won't update increment if the user do not really download it. But I noticed that despite pressing cancel, the increment is still being updated. The file involved in this downloading is small, around 100kb or more.

In my opinion, the for loop is already done, before `Response.IsClientConnected` becomes false. What can I change to make this work? Any pointer would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the property `IsClientConnected` after having sent the entire response. If the client cancelled or disconnected meanwhile it will tell you so.

What's important is that you check this property before calling `End` on the response stream, otherwise the connection is closed anyway.

So basically it comes down to:

- Send your data
- Verify that the client is still connected
- Close the connection

Optionally you might want to check this value even while delivering your data to the client regularly.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx) for details.

Comment: sorry, I'm not quite familiar with the handler. So I should be putting this, `if (context.Response.IsClientConnected == true)`, after this, `context.Response.End();` ?

Comment: No, just before calling `End` (otherwise the connection is closed anyway). Basically, you need to do it after having sent all the data, but before closing the connection.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my question, can you have a look at it? I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my placing of `IsClientConnected`.